# Why am I getting this issue?

Tags: c#, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a simple calculator in C# but I'm getting some errors.

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace calculator_c_sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Calculator inputs

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the first integer.");
            int int1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the second integer.");
            int int2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter operation.");
            string oper = Console.ReadLine();

            //Calculator solving

            if (oper == "+") ;
            {
                int ans = int1 + int2;
                Console.WriteLine("Answer = " + ans);
            }

            else if (oper == "-") ;
            {
                int ans = int1 - int2;
                Console.WriteLine("Answer = " + ans);
            }

            else if (oper == "*");
            {
                int ans = int1 * int2;
                Console.WriteLine("Answer = " + ans);
            }

            else if (oper == "/") ;
            {
                int ans = int1 / int2;
                Console.WriteLine("Answer = " + ans);
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error.");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Visual Studio is saying there's an error at the bottom } after every if statement.

[image: Image here]

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Stop just inserting semicolons everywhere. Pay attention to what the green squiggles are trying to tell you.

Comment: You don't need semicolons after the `if` condition, the `if` and the contents of the `{}` are considered one statement so shouldn't have `;` in between.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, where the code says `if (oper == "+") ;`, exactly what do you think this means? Specifically, what do you think the `;` will do? Do you see why this would cause a problem, if you want to have a block of code inside `{}` after that?

Comment: Also, for future reference: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If you have code to do something similar four times in a row, and each time causes the same problem, **we only need to see one**. Instead of showing us the code that you are trying to fix, show us code **that demonstrates the problem directly**. A good example will also use simple, hard-coded input.

Comment: remove semicolon after if that it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No semicolon after `if else` or other keywords of the nature.

```
        if (oper == "+")
        {
            int ans = int1 + int2;
            Console.WriteLine("Answer = " + ans);
        }

        else if (oper == "-")
        {
            int ans = int1 - int2;
            Console.WriteLine("Answer = " + ans);
        }

        else if (oper == "*")
        {
            int ans = int1 * int2;
            Console.WriteLine("Answer = " + ans);
        }

        else if (oper == "/")
        {
            int ans = int1 / int2;
            Console.WriteLine("Answer = " + ans);
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error.");
        }
```

Comment: Except `do {/*code*/} while(/*condition*/);`

Comment: True, that block ends with semicolon.